# Error while splitting data Randomly: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to split my data into train and test data set. I am using numpy uniform method. Here is my code:

```
self.fullData['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(self.fullData)) <= .75
Train, Test = self.fullData[self.fullData['is_train']==True], self.fullData[self.fullData['is_train']==False]
```

When I execute this code, I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

After searching for the solution of this error, I came up with this solution, that is I selected specific features in which I was sure that there were no NaN values and those were all I wanted for my predictive model. Here is the code:

```
            temp = DataFrame()
            temp = self.fullData[list(self.features)].values[:,8]

            temp['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(temp)) <= .75
            Train, Test = temp[temp['is_train']==True], temp[temp['is_train']==False]
```

However, after executing the above code. I am getting the following error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code or my data. I need some assistance.

Comment: Could it be the comma in the `values` slice here? `temp = self.fullData[list(self.features)].values[:,8]`

Comment: I removed [:,8] but still same error

Comment: I think he meant "try `...values[:8]` instead".

Comment: Please provide a [mwe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which produces the first error kind. I tried your code and it worked with an artificial dataset.

Comment: The first error kind occurs from the 1st code I provided. Here are the attributes of the data set. ['low', 'high', 'market_cap', 'daily_average_volume_10', 'daily_average_volume_30', 'monthly_return', 'annualized_volatility', 'weekly_return', 'open'] 

All of them are float data type

Comment: I wonder if your array is actually a pandas series with a mixed dtype, maybe object with nan or None.  You need a bunch of diagnostic prints.

Comment: Here are some values of it

[[  5.53800000e+01   5.58500000e+01   3.63000000e+11 ...,   2.62518870e-01
    1.95934810e-02   5.54300000e+01]
 ..., 
 [             nan              nan              nan ...,              nan
               nan              nan]
 [             nan              nan              nan ...,              nan
               nan              nan]
 [             nan              nan              nan ...,              nan
               nan              nan]]